Correct pyasn1 data structure for IEC 61850 sample values SavPDU type?
I'm trying to convert a SEQUENCE type to a Python class model following the Berkeley published PyASN1 programmer's manual documentation.
The IEC 61850-9-2 Section 8.5.2 Table 14 Encoding for a SavPdu is defined as
    SavPdu ::= SEQUENCE {
            noASDU   [0] IMPLICIT INTEGER (1..65535),
            security [1] ANY OPTIONAL,
            asdu     [2] IMPLICIT SEQUENCE OF ASDU        
    }

    ASDU ::= SEQUENCE {
        svID        [0] IMPLICIT VisibleString,
        datset      [1] IMPLICIT VisibleString OPTIONAL,
        smpCnt      [2] IMPLICIT OCTET STRING (SIZE(2)),
        confRev     [3] IMPLICIT OCTET STRING (SIZE(4)),
        refrTm      [4] IMPLICIT UtcTime OPTIONAL,
        smpSynch    [5] IMPLICIT OCTET STRING (SIZE(1)),
        smpRate     [6] IMPLICIT OCTET STRING (SIZE(2)) OPTIONAL,
        sample      [7] IMPLICIT OCTET STRING (SIZE(n)),
        smpMod      [8] IMPLICIT OCTET STRING (SIZE(2)) OPTIONAL
    }

This is my first attempt at creating a Python class for the above model:
from pyasn1.type import constraint, namedtype, tag, univ

class SavPdu(univ.Sequence):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
        namedtype.NamedType('noASDU', univ.Integer().subtype(subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueRangeConstraint(1,65535), implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 0))),
        namedtype.OptionalNamedType('security', univ.Any().subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 1))), 
        namedtype.NamedType('asdu', univ.SequenceOf(componentType=ASDU()).subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple,2)))
    )

where ASDU is another Python class defined elsewhere in the file.
Am I defining my class correctly based on the model and library?

What does the result look like?  Without an isea of what the intended result is expected to look like, we are not in a position to judge if you are doing it correctly.

@itprorh66 - I cannot answer that, as that is what I am trying to find out. What does the Python pyasn1 class definition look like given the ASN1 model.
